# Node.JS application will run on localhost but not URL via iisnode

Tags: node.js, windows, iis, azure-virtual-machine, iisnode

I have a node.js application that runs fine when I go to localhost:3000, however when I try and access it via the url using iisnode, it returns the following.

> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a
>   production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale
>   past a single process. Pipe production requires elevated privileges

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you could access the node.js application directly on the server, but if you use the IP address it throw the error?

For the warning, it seems that you hve used the MemoryStore to store the session. MemoryStore is just for development mode, it may cause this issue.

I suggest you could try to use [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) package.

To do this simply install cookie-session:

```
npm install cookie-session
```

Then in your app.js, find where express-session is being used and replace with cookie-session.

```
app.use(require('cookie-session')({
    // Cookie config, take a look at the docs...
}));
```

Comment: Thank You! Installing and replacing with cookie-session got rid of part of the error.  The only part left is:

Pipe production requires elevated privileges

So if I access the application via localhost:port it works without an issue.  When I go to the url assigned (hosted in iis via iisnode) I get the error.